# Add field to FDMemTable in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi

I am coding something with DBGrid and there is not enough data witch i cen get with FDQuery. I would like custom data beside "FDQuery" data. I found component that should be able to do this and it is called FDMemTable. I can get data from FDQuery to FDMemTable, but I cant add a new field where I can put different data. So my question is how to propper connect the data with FDQuery and add extra column in FDMemTable.

```
procedure TWorkflowDM.Temp;
var
  Error: string;
  Temp: string;
begin
  try
    FDQuery1.Open;
    FDQuery1.FetchAll;
    FDMemTable1.Data:= FDQuery1.Data;
    FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('Test', ftString, 20, False);        <-ERROR (Error 'FDMemTable1: Field ''Test'' not found')
    FDMemTable1.Open;
    FDMemTable1.First;
    while not FDMemTable1.Eof do
    begin
      Temp:= FDMemTable1.FieldByName('Test').AsString;
      FDMemTable1.Next;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Error:= E.Message;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You can add an empty column (field) in your SQL statement without having to jump through hoops or using an in-memory table.

Comment: @KenWhite For combining SQL query dataset with other data. How can I add empty column in SQL query. I'm using Firebird.

Comment: `SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, '          ' AS MyNewCol FROM MyTable WHERE SomeCondition` adds a new character column that accepts up to 10 characters. You can then use `FieldByName('MyNewCol')` elsewhere. (Of course, replace *MyNewCol* with whatever other column alias you'd like.) If the DBMS you're using supports functions like `REPEAT` or `REPLICATE`, you can use them instead of the empty spaces.

Comment: @KenWhite Also working good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We copy the field  definitions from the source DataSet and append the additional fields. Then we call `CreateDataset` or [optionally set Active to true](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.CreateDataSet). This creates all the necessary fields and opens the `FDMemTable`. Then we populate it by CopyDataset method. This code works:

```
procedure TWorkflowDM.Temp;
var
  Error: string;
  Temp: string;
begin
  try
    FDQuery1.Open;
    // FDQuery1.FetchAll;
    FDMemTable1.FieldDefs := FDQuery1.FieldDefs;
    FDMemTable1.FieldDefs.Add('Test', ftString, 20{, False}); // default parameter
    FDMemTable1.CreateDataSet;//or just Open that sets Active to true; 
    FDMemTable1.CopyDataSet(FDQuery1);
    FDMemTable1.First;
    while not FDMemTable1.Eof do
    begin
      Temp := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('Test').AsString;
      FDMemTable1.Next;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Error := E.Message;
  end;
end;
```